# Strange behaviour with Line Breaks

Tags: formatting

When placing Terms in several lines for better readability it comes to a strange behavior:

```
(* this works ==> fx1[1, 3,5,7,11,13] = -25 *)
fx1[pa1_, pa2_, pa3_, pb1_, pb2_, pb3_] :=
  (pa1*pb1) + (pa2*pb2) - (pa3*pb3);

(* this works, too ==> fx2[1, 3,5,7,11,13] = -25 *)
fx2[pa1_, pa2_, pa3_, pb1_, pb2_, pb3_] :=
  (pa1*pb1) +
   (pa2*pb2) -
   (pa3*pb3);

(* this does not ==> fx3[1, 3,5,7,11,13] = -7 *)
fx3[pa1_, pa2_, pa3_, pb1_, pb2_, pb3_] :=
  (pa1*pb1)
   + (pa2*pb2)
   - (pa3*pb3);
```

This happens in M8 as well as in M10 so I guess it's not a bug... 
**but why?**
and **can I avoid this?**

Comment: [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66896/)

Comment: note if you wrap the whole thing in `(  )` or other constructs such as `Module`, you can break the lines as you please.  I always do so if the expression is big enough to need breaks.