# single-line running one by one VS write all sentences together

Tags: writing

The three sentences in the picture below, there is no problem with single-line running one by one, but why put it together to run with one "shift+enter" will have a problem, I don't understand the error prompt given by Mathematica.

[image]
<= still don't know why

more tests(seem approaching answer):

[image]

---

Refer to the example below, it seems that the key to whether they can be written together is whether there is ambiguity, but I still haven't figured out what the full criterion is.

[image: pic2]

<= this question have been solved in this answer(thanks Domen):
[What is the correct way to break a long expression across multiple lines?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66896/what-is-the-correct-way-to-break-a-long-expression-across-multiple-lines)

<= but later i find "\" and "esc+cont+ecs" is useless(please see the picture below) in the notebook cell, so how can i break a long expression across multiple lines in the notebook cell?

[image: pic1]

---

btw, is there a writing way can writing multi sentences in one-line? I mean we can achieve this effect by ";"(1+1;2+2; ---- in one line), but we can't see answer using ";", is there a writing way to both separate multi commands and display the results?

<= not sure existing of the way

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Does this answer your question? [What is the correct way to break a long expression across multiple lines?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66896/what-is-the-correct-way-to-break-a-long-expression-across-multiple-lines)

Comment: @Domen thanks, that's helps(for question in second question), but still i don't figure out the problem in the first picture

Comment: I think the `??` operator just has very high precedence.  You can never use it in an input cell with other expressions.

Comment: sorry, not very understand your explanation. but i have done more tests in the above